# Как по фэн-шую получить путь к AppData для пользователя отличного от текущего?

Tags: c#, windows, .net

Существует замечательный метод достать путь к папке AppData текущего пользователя:

```
string applicationDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Метод хорош тем, что не зависит от реального расположения папки пользователя, версии ОС и тому подобного.

Собственно, хотелось бы увидеть способ достать путь к AppData не только для текущего пользователя, но для любого, если у меня есть строка логина этого пользователя.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Задача оказалась сложнее, чем предполагалось :-)

Для начала, вам нужно воспользоваться P/Invoke, встроенного в .NET пути нет. Например, [вы можете воспользоваться](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031103-00/?p=41973) функцией [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) с подходящим [`KNOWNFOLDERID`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid). Подключается она [вот так](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetKnownFolderPath.html).

Вам понадобится `AccessToken`, который можно получить при помощи функции [`LogonUser`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) как описано в примере [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8):

```
public class FolderDemo
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername,
        String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid, uint dwFlags,
        IntPtr hToken, out IntPtr pszPath);

    // If you incorporate this code into a DLL, be sure to demand FullTrust.
    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get the user token for the specified user, domain, and password
        // using the unmanaged LogonUser method. 
        // The local machine name can be used for the domain name to
        // impersonate a user on this machine.
        string domainName = ...;    
        string userName = ...;
        string userPassword = ...;

        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        //This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token. 
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

        IntPtr handle;

        // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token. 
        bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, userPassword,
            LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
            out handle);

        if (!returnValue)
            return;

        try
        {
            // судя по всему, можно объявить SHGetKnownFolderPath
            // поинтеллектуальнее, чтобы не понадобилось маршалирование вручную
            IntPtr pPath;
            if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(KnownFolder.LocalAppData, 0, handle,
                                     out pPath) == 0)
            {
                string path = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pPath);
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pPath);
                // тут строку можно использовать
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // обязательно! а то останемся с правами другого юзера
            CloseHandle(handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Класс `KnownFolder` смотрите [тут](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetKnownFolderPath.html), интересующая вас часть такая:

```
public static class KnownFolder
{
    public static readonly Guid LocalAppData =
            new Guid("F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091");
    public static readonly Guid LocalAppDataLow =
            new Guid("A520A1A4-1780-4FF6-BD18-167343C5AF16");
    public static readonly Guid RoamingAppData =
            new Guid("3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D");
    // ...
}
```

---

[Кажется](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/need-to-free-memory-after-p-invoke.2900527/), можно переопределить `SHGetKnownFolderPath` так, чтобы не вызывать вручную `FreeCoTaskMem`:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
public static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid, uint dwFlags,
    IntPtr hToken, out String path);

...

string path;
if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(KnownFolder.LocalAppData, 0, handle,
                                     out path) == 0)
{
    // тут строку можно использовать
}
```

Но я не уверен на 100%, interop всегда полон неожиданностей.

Comment: Похоже, что не IntPtr.Zero, а handle.

Comment: @AlexeyM: точно, спасибо! Ради этого хэндла, собственно, весь предыдущий код и затеян. Исправлено.