# Расшифровка Wi-Fi пароля

Tags: c#, winapi, wifi

Добрый день. Встала задача расшифровать сохраненный в системе пароль от wi-fi.
Пример файла содержания (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces):

```
<keyMaterial>01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C04FC297EB01000000B5DC49CF346C5441ACC9412051EEA53100000000020000000000106600000001000020000000B0BCA6C2C90D3F05AE7F43835F1CB0E8B9ECBCF351138A83B9E94228181CAC9E000000000E8000000002000020000000630621CC8DE9EBBFBE1089010AE6ABF4C531E277F18DC576E4EBDEB43C0D238110000000778F49BCC7B5CC0D032ECFAD9CD5419E4000000054FCFB5D2A46A1BD944F1A42B27C6B1A0CD19E5101DA4B4307DEBD5ECE980E3AEB62E1959060720459C2A854BA9100C9E912AC076A49D13B0B935942FDF4BF11</keyMaterial>
```

Суть проблемы - не срабатывает, выдает исключение: CryptUnprotectData failed.

Вызов:

```
string entropy = null;
        string description;

        string Pass = @"01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C04FC297EB01000000B5DC49CF346C5441ACC9412051EEA53100000000020000000000106600000001000020000000B0BCA6C2C90D3F05AE7F43835F1CB0E8B9ECBCF351138A83B9E94228181CAC9E000000000E8000000002000020000000630621CC8DE9EBBFBE1089010AE6ABF4C531E277F18DC576E4EBDEB43C0D238110000000778F49BCC7B5CC0D032ECFAD9CD5419E4000000054FCFB5D2A46A1BD944F1A42B27C6B1A0CD19E5101DA4B4307DEBD5ECE980E3AEB62E1959060720459C2A854BA9100C9E912AC076A49D13B0B935942FDF4BF11";

        byte[] Key = null;

            // Call DPAPI to decrypt data.
        string decrypted = DPAPI.Decrypt(Pass, entropy, out description);

        richTextBox1.Text = decrypted;
```

Вспомогательный класс: http://dumpz.org/1173308/

Comment: сделайте код покороче. Сильно сомневаюсь, что все содержимое необходимо для понимания проблемы (во всяком случае комментарии, занимающие процентов 40 листинга)

Comment: @z668L Ага, уже лучше. Вот обсуждение по вашей проблеме: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/10822536/276994>. (Я тоже сейчас почитаю.)

Comment: @z668: Ага, кажется, разобрался. Значит так. Во-первых, надо сначала распаковать строку (у вас кажется hex-encoded). Здесь может быть ошибка: ваш код раскодирует, кажется, из [base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Вторая возможная проблема (после того, как вы справитесь с первой) — вам нужно вызывать `CryptUnprotectData` из-под экаунта Local System. Вы делаете так?

Comment: @z668: Смотрите. Если вам нужно только раскодировать пароль, в конце ответа есть полный пример на плюсах. Можно просто взять его.

Если вы хотите именно встроить этот код в C#, возможно (не уверен!) достаточно просто запустить его от имени администратора. Если нет — вам придётся реализовывать смену текущего юзера при помощи P/Invoke. Вот [отсюда](/questions/227200/) можно выцепить пример, вам нужна функция `LogonUser`. Но тут, возможно, придётся экспериментировать дальше.

Comment: @VladD, исключил всю нативную хрень, сейчас основываюсь только на System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect() - обертка над interop, используя PsExec удалось запустить под LocalSystem и получить пароль. Дело осталось за малым - запускать программно под LocalSystem.

Comment: @z668: О, уже лучше. А код [отсюда](/questions/227200/) не пробовали? А из-под админа не идёт?

---
Вот [ещё пример](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Ок, благодарю. Буду пробовать, обязательно отпишусь по результатам. Из под амина ни в какую.

Comment: @z668: Там конечно тоже полунативная хрень с P/Invoke, но по крайней мере официальный майкрософтовский пример.

Comment: @VladD, нашел класс [ImpersonateUser](http://dumpz.org/1173481/) 
В принципе он выдает адекватное исключение: http://i5.5cm.ru/i/WiNh.png
Пробовал по разному, и LoacalSystem, и System, и даже Система - не помогает. Пароль - оставлял пустую строку. Даже не знаю куда копать теперь.

Comment: @VladD, хороший человек с кибера помог разобраться в ситуации, [ссылка](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread1240928.html#post6508832)

Comment: @VladD, вы человек? Вы так много знаете в множестве разных технологий, что заставили меня усомниться.

Comment: @maestro: Нас тут целый институт сидит и пишет ответы на самом деле (но никому не рассказывайте, а то премии лишат).

Comment: VladD -- человек и институт! :)

Comment: @maestro хороший технарь не обязан знать и помнить все, но обязан быстро сориентироваться по входным данным, дополнить недостаток информации с найти верное решение. Поэтому лично мне отвечать на вопросы интереснее чем задавать их, это позволяет постоянно развиваться =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Собрал ответ из комментариев.)

Во-первых, надо сначала распаковать строку (у вас, кажется, hex-encoded). Здесь может быть ошибка: ваш код раскодирует, кажется, из [base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Вторая возможная проблема (после того, как вы справитесь с первой) — вам нужно вызывать `CryptUnprotectData` из-под экаунта Local System.

Если вам нужно только раскодировать пароль, в конце [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10822536/276994) есть полный пример на плюсах. Можно просто взять его. Если вы хотите именно встроить этот код в C#, возможно (не уверен!), достаточно просто запустить его от имени администратора. Если нет — вам придётся реализовывать смену текущего юзера при помощи P/Invoke. Вот [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/227200/10105) можно выцепить пример, вам нужна функция `LogonUser`. Но тут, возможно, придётся экспериментировать дальше.

---

По результатам обсуждения, `PsExec` таки помогло.

Comment: Да да, я с PsExec и буду делать как самый адекватный вариант.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, приятно когда грамотные специалисты помогают разобраться в теме, побольше бы таких как Вы и Олег с кибера.