# Запрос пароля администратора во время выполнения программы на C++ (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi

В манифесте приложения на C++ указаны параметры для запуска с правами администратора (`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>`). По непонятным мне причинам такой подход породил следующую проблему:

функция `SHGetFolderPath` с флагом `CSIDL_APPDATA` возвращает путь админа, который введёт пароль, а не пользователя, который запустил приложение. Это критично, поскольку приложение является установщиком ПО, и писать конфиги и прочие рабочие установки должно именно в папку запустившего его пользователя, которым может быть и гость. К сожалению использование `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` не решает проблему, так как распаковываемые установщиком сторонние приложения ищут свои конфиги именно в папке пользователя, и общая APPDATA их не "интересует".

Подскажите пожалуйста выход из данной ситуации - как назначить запрос прав администратора только на кнопку "Установить", чтобы при старте установщик успел подхватить правильные пути?

PS: Путь получается так:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(wParam){
        case 1:
            ...
            //Получение ключевых путей в глобальные переменные
            SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, 0, AppDataRoaming);
            SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, NULL, 0, AppDataLocal);
            SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAMS, NULL, 0, StartMenu);
            SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_DESKTOP, NULL, 0, DeskTop);

            ...
            //Запуск извлечения файлов.
            DWORD dwThreadId;
            InstallThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, DataProcessing, NULL, 0, &dwThreadId);
            ...
            break;
        ...
```

Естественно получение путей можно вынести до кнопки установить, но надо решить проблему с доступом администратора, который запрашивается сразу при старте (иконка приложения с "щитом")

Comment: Покажите кусок кода, где вызывается `SHGetFolderPath`

Comment: Написал пример кода...

Answer (score 3):

Всё работает согласно документации.

`SHGetFolderPath` [является обёрткой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx) к `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.
Из [документации к `SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx%60):

> `hToken` [in, optional]
>
> Type: `HANDLE`
>
> An access token that represents a particular user. If this parameter is `NULL`, which is the most common usage, the function requests the known folder for the current user.

Поскольку ваш текущий пользователь — админ, вы получаете то, что запрашивали.

---

Для того, чтобы отдельно получить нужные пути, и отдельно запуститься из-под админа, вам нужно сделать следующее:

1. Убрать манифест, запускать программу без него. В ней у вас есть данные текущего юзера.
2. После диалога с пользователем нужно запустить *свой же собственный процесс параллельно*, затребовав при этом админские права. Пример кода [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4893508/276994).
3. Администраторский экземпляр процесса инсталлятора по-хорошему не должен создавать файлы для текущего пользователя, т. к. они будут созданы с администраторскими правами (если не позаботиться об ином специально). Поэтому имеет смысл дождаться окончания работы администраторского процесса в неадминистраторском процессе, и с правами текущего пользователя создать нужные файлы.

Comment: А можно как-нибудь получить каталог только гостевой учётной записи, чтобы продублировать нужные файлы конфигов туда и не переделывать большой кусок установщика? (предполагается, что пользователи должны работать с пакетом из-под гостя)

Comment: @Iceman: Ну например можно получить токен нужного юзера и impersonation. Посмотрите код [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/227212/10105).

Comment: Ну например можно получить токен нужного юзера и impersonation. Посмотрите код [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/227212/10105).

Answer (score 0):

В различных источниках написано, что в таком вот (вашем) случае для функции `SHGetFolderPath()` третий параметр `hToken` нужно заполнять реальным значением, а не NULL. Гляньте в сторону `WTSQuerySessionInformation()` потом `WTSQueryUserToken()`.

Comment: Странно, WTSQueryUserToken() - вообще незнакомая функция для MinGW (-l wtsapi32 в компоновщике прописано, заголовок тоже).